# contact form 7 (Multistep) auto-fill field

Tags: contact-form-7, autofill, multi-step

I am trying to create a multiform with the plugin "contact form 7". Everything is working well with the form, but I am trying to get to the first form values in the second form.

For example, my first form field is zip code. When I go to the second form, the first form values should be auto-filled in the second form's zip code field.

Here is the [example website](http://gomedigap.com/)

I want to create the same process. Please help!

Comment: CF7 doesn’t offer any multi-step functionality on its own AFAIK, so you might be best off with using an additional plugin for that purpose. (https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-multi-step/ was the first that came up in my quick search.)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try cf7 multi-step plugin.